# problems reading int from bytearray

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays

This is my first question, so do not judge strictly.
 I have an object that I'm getting from php server to as3(flash) client. That object is AMF encoded, so I write server response to ByteArray:

```
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
ba.writeUTFBytes( rawData );
```

and than I'm reading object from ByteArray:

```
ba.position = 0;
var response:Object = ba.readObject();
```

Part of object contains such data:

```
{
 'money' : 900
}
```

And when reading object from ByteArray, I get a seven-digit number ~ 1824344 instead of 900. But when I get form server String '900' or int value equals 100 - data reads correctly.

Has someone had such a problem?

Comment: Should you be using `readUTFBytes()` instead of `readObject()`?

Comment: no, coz I receiving an object

Comment: I think you need to include both the full code that reads the object, and, just as important, the entire object it is reading.

Comment: What data type is rawData? I have a feeling rawData is not what you think it is.

Comment: rawData is an String presentation of AMF encoded object, that i got from the php sever in HTTP POST request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read the same way you wrote. If you write something using `writeUTFBytes()`, you have to read it using `readUTFBytes()`.

In this case you should use `writeObject()` and `readObject()` because you are writing pure Object but not String.

Comment: God point. But what I getting in a POST request& Isn't it a String?
And I'll try it. But in nine hours.

Comment: If responce is encoded in AMF - it is not a string. It is serialized to binary data AS3/AS2 object.

Comment: But now in you previous comments I see that AMF object from server is passed as a string. I guess that AMF object on server is encoded as Base64 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). If it is that you have to get Base64 decoder (such as this: http://jpauclair.net/2010/01/09/base64-optimized-as3-lib/) and by using it convert that string to byte array. Then from that byte array you can read Object using readObject() method.